What about using bare “self” as a reflexive pronoun?
When I encounter reflexive “self” in English, it is always connected to a pronoun (“myself”, “himself”). But, because it always refers to the subject of the sentence, it seems that the pronoun part does not add any information. That leads to that I tend to use just “self” as the reflexive pronoun. How is it perceived by native English speakers?
Examples:

The dog is scratching self.


She is very pleased with self.


Who takes care of self is healthier.


They are congratulating selves.

This idea comes from English words like “self-preservation” and “self-destruction”, where “self” alone is used reflexively. I understand these words as “preservation of self” and “destruction of self”. Looking into dictionaries, I see that “self” alone was in English first as a pronoun (in the middle ages), but it is not used in that way any more, so I think that my examples are according to the English grammar but archaic.

They are all wrong, and for the reason you (yourself) stated: it is always connected to a pronoun. That's the rule.

We would perceive it as definitely wrong.
The better approach is to understand that in English there are a range of pronouns with different forms and functions, and you do have to learn them. So for example, myself is a specific pronoun, and when it applies, that's the word. You can't cut it in half.
You're also wrong when you say:

because it always refers to the subject of the sentence, it seems that the pronoun part does not add any information.

Compare these sentences:

The dog is scratching itself.
The dog is scratching its leg.
The dog is scratching the chair.

In sentence #1, itself adds as much information as the objects in the other two sentences. In all three cases we learn what is being scratched. Yes, in the first sentence the subject and object are the same, which is why the reflexive pronoun is required. But itself is certainly not a redundant word.

I don't understand your point with comparing the sentences. Does “itself” in sentence 1 add more information than just “self” would? I think that these two cases (#1 with “itself” and #1 with “self”) have the same meaning.

That's the wrong question. The real question is, which word is correct? Answer: "itself". In this setting, "self" alone is a nonsense word. To give you a silly example, suppose I ask you why we say scratching in those sentences? Why don't we just say "scrat"? Answer: because there's no such word. It's made up. It's nonsense. Likewise, in all your examples, self is not a pronoun that exists for that purpose. It just doesn't exist the way you are trying to use it.

That's not what "self" means.  The dictionary gives:

(countable noun) a person's essential being that distinguishes them from others

So "She is very pleased with self" is incorrect grammar.  The noun "self" needs a determiner.  And if you write "the self", the word "self" doesn't have to refer to the subject.  You could say "I am pleased with my daughter's self"  (it is a weird thing to say, but it is grammatically correct).  It means that you are pleased with your daughter's essential being.
What an odd thing to say!
If you just want the reflexive pronoun you have to use the reflexive pronoun. The word "self" isn't a reflexive pronoun.  You have to use "herself" in that example.  The "her" is not redundant, neither logically nor grammatically.

There are cases where “self” alone is used as a reflexive pronoun. “self-preservation”, which I understand as “preservation of self”, and words like that.

There are, but English speakers would never use self on its own in the way you have tried to use it.

Note also that "myself" and "my self" have different meanings, and the second is very unusual in normal conversation. The second might occur in a conversation about philosophy, in which case one might discuss a man talking about his self, which is not the same as the man talking about himself.

"self-preservation" isn't the word "self" used as a reflexive pronoun.  It's a compound word.  I have no idea why you think that is a "pronoun"! The word "self" no more a pronoun than the word "foot".  And when you say "football" the word "foot" isn't a pronoun.
